# Intellij does not recognize code changes in scala main object

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Whenever I make changes to the code in my main object in Intellij, they dont get picked up. But when i run sbt clean assembly, the Run button picks up my code changes. not sure what's going wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you got to `Edit configurations...` for your run configuration, does it say `Build` in the `Before launch` section?

Comment: yes it does thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, if any unknown intellij error occurs, I do below action.

```
File > invalidate Caches / Restart > INVALID AND RESTART
```

Hope it helps.